# Unity, Why in c# script when using the var animation some properties not exist?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

What i want to do is automatic make the character to walk to a specific position or just walk to a specific direction.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Ai : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        var v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        if(Mathf.Abs(v) > 0.1f) {
            animation["Walk"].speed = v;
            animation.CrossFade("Walk");
            transform.position.z += v;
        }
        else animation.CrossFade("Idle");
    }
}
```

speed and the CrossFade not exist.

Update what i tried :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Ai : MonoBehaviour {

    Animation animation;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        var v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        if(Mathf.Abs(v) > 0.1f) {
            animation["Walk"].speed = v;
            animation.CrossFade ("Walk");
            transform.position.z += v;
        }
        else animation.CrossFade("Idle");


    }
}
```

Made the animation global variable of Animation.
Now the animation have the properties speed and CrossFade but now i'm getting a new warning and a new error:

The warning is on the line:

```
Animation animation;
```

`Ai.animation' hides inherited member`UnityEngine.Component.animation'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended

And the error is on the line:

```
transform.position.z += v;
```

Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Transform.position'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `var` stands for anonymous types. They will only resolved at compiler time.

As Pieter Witvoet mentions in the comment, normally the intellisense should have no problem with implicitly typed variables.

But in your case you're overlapping two properties and so now the IDE get's confused.

So right now your intellisense is not award which class explicit your object is.

Simply replace `var animation` with `Animation animation` and your intellisense provide all missing functions and properties.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

---

To your second Question:

```
transform.position.z += new Vector3(0,0,v);
```

The `Vector3` properties for x,y an z are all read only.

Comment: I added before the Start function: Animation animation; then all the properties now exist but then i'm getting a new warning and a new error. The warning is on the line Animation animation; `Ai.animation' hides inherited member `UnityEngine.Component.animation'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended and the error is on the line transform.position.z += v; Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Transform.position'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

Comment: Was it right to make global variable of animation ? And then why the warning and the error ?

Comment: Just rename your Variable from `animation` to something like `_animation` or `aiAnimation`.

Comment: Changed the variable Animation animation; to Animation _animation; so the warning is gone now. but still i'm getting the error on the line: transform.position.z += v; Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Transform.position'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

Comment: This is an own question. Moving Objects don't work like this `transform.position.z += v;`. Look at http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/set-value-on-gameobject-transform-position-x-with-c.66768/

Comment: I'm getting two errors now on the line transform.position.z += new Vector3(0,0,v);  the first one: Operator `+=' cannot be applied to operands of type `float' and `UnityEngine.Vector3' and the second one: Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Transform.position'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

Comment: `var` is for [implicit typing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx), it does not imply the use of anonymous types. Intellisense should have no problem with implicitly typed variables (depending on what IDE one uses, I suppose).

Comment: @Smartis you just updated you answer with the same line that give the same errors.  Should i change something with the transform ? Make it variable like with the _animation ? Tried to make a variable _transform of Transform in the top of the script but it give me the same errors.

Comment: Another exception i keep getting all the time is on the line in the end: else _animation.CrossFade("Idle"); before that i had a warning on the line in the top Animation _animation; that it will always will be null since it's not assigned. So i did Animation _animation = new Animation(); so the warning is gone but the null exception is now show.

Comment: @TheLostLostit The problem here is a lack of knowledge. I would recommend you to look up Unitys own Tutorials first. They provide really clear examples of all this.

`Animation` is not a class you instantiated with a constructor. It's a component you add to the `MonoBehavior` Object.  

Your current question is complete. Please mark it as answered.